# Filter rows in a specific range values containing character and number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I'm using RStudio to perform some analysis.

I have this data frame:

| Residue | Energy | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R-A-40 | -3.45 | DELTA |
| R-A-350 | -1.89 | DELTA |
| R-B-468 | -0.25 | DELTA |
| R-C-490 | -2.67 | DELTA |
| R-A-610 | -1.98 | DELTA |

I would like to filter the first column ("Residue") based on the numeric values (between 300 to 500) and create a new data frame. The new data frame would be like this:

| Residue | Energy | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R-A-350 | -1.89 | DELTA |
| R-B-468 | -0.25 | DELTA |
| R-C-490 | -2.67 | DELTA |

Note that it does not matter if starts with "R-A-", "R-B-" or "R-C-". However, I have different patterns (not only these three). I have to ignore the non-numeric characters or the first four characters from "Residue" column.

I did not find any similar question. I appreciate any help!

Thanks an advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `stringr`s `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)

val <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$Residue, "[[:digit:]]+"))

df[val > 300 & val < 500,]
  Residue Energy Model
2 R-A-350  -1.89 DELTA
3 R-B-468  -0.25 DELTA
4 R-C-490  -2.67 DELTA
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Residue = c("R-A-40", "R-A-350", "R-B-468", "R-C-490", 
"R-A-610"), Energy = c(-3.45, -1.89, -0.25, -2.67, -1.98), Model = c("DELTA", 
"DELTA", "DELTA", "DELTA", "DELTA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# convert character to integer
df$x <- as.integer(substr(df$Residue, 5, nchar(df$Residue)))

# subset
df[df$x %between% c(300,500), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to one of the answers already given, but a little more readable:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~Residue, ~Energy,    ~Model,
              "R-A-40", -3.45,  "DELTA",
              "R-A-350",    -1.89, "DELTA",
              "R-B-468",    -0.25,  "DELTA")
df %>% 
  mutate(number = str_extract(Residue, "[:DIGIT:]+")) %>% 
  mutate(number = as.numeric(number)) %>% 
  filter(number >= 300 & number <= 500)
```